# How to toggle Menu in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic, and I am developing a basic app in Ionic 4 with `sidemenu`.

**I am adding a button in Side Menu**, when I am clicking on that button the menu is not toggling. can anyone help me in this ?
here's the code which I am trying.

`<ion-button color="primary" (click)="function()" class="class" menuToggle expand="block" fill="outline">
    text
 </ion-button>`

> Explanation of not Duplicate question

Please check the Bold text, I already have a working sidemenu, but the problem is I want to close the sidemenu when I click on `ion-button`, not on `ion-item`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 4 adding side menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657275/ionic-4-adding-side-menu)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Simply encapsulate your `ion-button` within an `ion-menu-toggle` element, like so:

```
<ion-menu-toggle>
  <ion-button>Toggle Menu</ion-button>
</ion-menu-toggle>
```

[View the documentation here](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu-toggle)

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to use `ion-menu-toggle`, you can do this instead:

In your app.component.ts:

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular'; //import MenuController to access toggle() method.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    public menuCtrl: MenuController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

toggleMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.toggle(); //Add this method to your button click function
  }

}
```

And in your app.component.html:

```
<ion-button (click)="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</ion-button>
```

To view all methods, [check the docs here](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried this also before, there was CSS issues. so planning to toggleMenu from function on click. :) thanks

Comment: For every new Ionic project I start I always forget to encapsulate with `ion-menu-toggle`, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

in your app.component.html:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane when="sm">
      <ion-menu>
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="primary" text-center>
            <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
              <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" href={{p.url}}>
                <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>
                  {{p.title}}
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
      <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: I want it for button, can you please help me in this ?

Comment: @riot  <ion-menu-toggle slot="end" class="benjam">
   
  
    <ion-icon name="grid-outline"></ion-icon>
   
    </ion-menu-toggle>