# How to call the menu toggle promise in ionic framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Can anyone give me a working example of how to use toggle promise in ionic using angular.

```
toggle(animated?: boolean) => Promise<boolean>
```

I want to call a user define function on menu close.How to use this the above toggle.I have [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803975/how-to-toggle-menu-in-ionic-4) but that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method returns a Promise with boolean, you need to call your own method after such Promise gets resolved:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-example.css'],
})
export class MenuExample {

constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }

  myCustomMethod() {
    // your custom method logic
  }

  openCustom() {
    this.menu.toggle(true).then((toggled) => {
        if (toggled) {
            this.myCustomMethod()
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app.html file

```
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main" (ionDidClose)="menuClosed()">
```

And then in your app.ts file you write your event handler functions

```
menuClosed() {
      //code to execute when menu has closed
}
```

**PS: ionDidClose is Emitted when the menu is closed.**